# Is "Blessed Reversal" treated as a single life gain event?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When playing [Blessed Reversal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blessed%20Reversal) is it treated as a single life gain event regardless of how many creatures are attacking? Or is each "3 life" treated as a separate event.

I'm asking because with [Heliod, Sun Crowned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Heliod%2C%20Sun%20Crowned) "Whenever you gain life, put a +1/+1 counter on target creature or enchantment you control." So if 10 creatures attack and I play Blessed Reversal, do I get 10 counters or 1 counter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Blessed Reversal is one lifegain event, even if more than one creature is attacking you. Heliod will create only one +1/+1 counter.**

The term "each creature attacking you" is a number that is determined when Blessed Reversal is resolved. The lifegain is a single one-shot effect and will trigger Heliod only once, if at least one creature is attacking you on resolution.

There are lifegain effects that create multiple "packages" of lifegain when you are attacked, such as [Righteous Cause](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Righteous%20Cause). Righteous Cause has a triggered ability that triggers individually for each creature that has been declared as an attacker.

It all depends on the wording though - there are also enchantments that create only one lifegain package for attacking creatures, such as [Orim's Prayer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Orim%27s%20Prayer).